# How do I traverse recursive object graph without duplicates in Swiftui with core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a simple recursive object in CoreData: (pseudo code)

```
class Person() {
var name: String
var friends: [Person]
}
```

and a listFriends view that adds personA's name to a VStack, and then calls itself for each of the personA's friends, so they get added to the list.

problem is, it then adds personA again because personA is one of personB's friends, and on, and on. So I now have a list of personA's 1st, 2nd and 3rd-degree friends, but there are a lot of repeat names on the list.

How can I get it to only display each name once?

I tried to maintain a separate array of printedNames, adding people to the printedNames just after Text(person.name) is called, but SwiftUI does strange things. The view seems to traverse the object graph many times before any names are actually drawn to the screen so having viewFriends check the array before adding a new name, did not work.

Comment: How are you accessing Core Data?  Are you using `@FetchRequest`? If so, I would suggest you don't do that.  Put your Core Data into a model object and then expose the friends via a function or computed property where you can eliminate duplicates

Comment: inside my ContentViewModel i create a array of all people using allItems = PersistenceController.shared.fetchAllItems() and then I have the view traverse that array to build the final social graph.

Comment: You need to work through your array and create some sort of hierarchy.  Decide how deep you want to go and whether you want to omit people that have already appeared at a higher level

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the help, I did as you suggest and now have what I want.